# “peak” vs “summit”

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns

According to the dictionary:

- *peak* — the pointed top of a mountain; a mountain with a pointed top
- *summit* — the highest point of something, especially the top of a mountain

In the picture of [the “mountain” word entry](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/mountain) in the *Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary*, they look the same: 
[image]

So, what is the difference between these two words in the meaning of a mountain top?

Comment: These words are exact synonyms.  In this context, there is no difference at all.  However, "peak" can also be used as an adjective, in ways that "summit" cannot.

Comment: @DavidWallace What is the use of having two words meaning the same thing? Usually there are slight differences in meaning or connotations between synonyms.

Comment: Hah!  Not this time.

Comment: @DavidWallace Maybe "summit" may be more level, while "peak" is always pointed? (I'm just guessing). :)

Comment: @DavidWallace OK! Could you form it as an answer for me to be able to accept it?

Comment: I would prefer not to.

Comment: Note how *summit* is labeled from above, while *peak* is labeled from below. Compare that to the two definitions you cite. *Peak* = the entire top, or even an entire mountain; *summit* = only one point, and never an entire mountain. This message has been proudly presented to you by The Hair Splitter.

Comment: "What is the use of having two words" - there probably isn't "a use". But languages are rarely so rational. It may be that these words had different usages in the past but are identical - in this context - today. It may be that their non-mountaineering uses are enough to differentiate them.

Comment: @RegDwight: Based solely on gut feel, I think I would've probably reversed those two definitions. Moreover, I think the word "summit" was printed above the peak simply to provide ample space between the word "summit" and the word "snow." (This message brought to you by The Other Side of the Coin.)

Comment: Interesting how [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain) proclaims, _"There is no universally accepted definition of a mountain._" It wouldn't surprise me if there's no universally accepted differentiation between _peak_ and _summit_, either. But the words are still aren't exactly interchangeable in all contexts – I wouldn't expect to see an engineer talk about "summit power" in a journal article, or hear about the State Department attending a "Peace Peak" in the Middle East.

Comment: @JR Looking at those two examples of failed applications of peak and summit, and also thinking about how, moving to the verb forms of these words, mountaineers wouldn't "peak a mountain" and I would never say my athletic ability "has summited," I wonder if the way we use these words involves "summit" being used for intentional goals, while "peak" is more about incidental measurements.

Comment: @ovgolovin - Sorry, I was completely wrong.  I answered without thinking too much.  Narengi's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you go by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographical_summit),

> In topography, a summit is a point on a surface that is higher in elevation than all points immediately adjacent to it. Mathematically, a summit is a local maximum in elevation. *The topographic terms "acme", "apex", "peak", and "zenith" are synonyms*.

According to [this glossary](http://www.summitpost.org/glossary-summit-peak-etc/173401),

> The summit is the highest point.
>
> *In theory*, every mountain has exactly one summit. *In practice*, mountaineers will in many cases talk about multiple summits (eg Everest South Summit), thus **blurring the distinction between "summit" and "peak"**.
>
> Sometimes as you're climbing you'll approach a spot that looks like it might be the summit, only to discover it's a "false summit".
>
> The word comes from Latin "summus", meaning "highest".
>
> In the 19th century, "summit" was also applied to other kinds of highest points, such as the highest point reached when crossing a pass.

The same glossary has an entry for *peak*:

> A peak is a point that's higher than all other adjacent points. In mathematical terms, it's a local maximum, the point with slope of zero along a convex-up curve. The thing to understand about this definition is that it is entirely localized: there may be some higher point not far away, but if you can't get there without going downhill first, you're standing on a peak.
>
> In other words, most mountains will have multiple peaks.

So, to sum it all up, unless you are particular about not piquing the interest of some topographical fusspot, it appears that there's nothing wrong in using the two terms interchangeably. However, *technically* speaking, a mountain can have only one summit, but multiple peaks. It follows that the lone summit is also a peak :)

Comment: By that definition, every single pebble is a peak. In hillwalking terms, the land must fall in all directions from a peak for a certain distance. That distance may depend on which guidebook you're reading at the time.

Answer (score 7):

Actually they are not the same. A ***peak*** is a point or an area that is higher than all adjacent areas So it's completely localized, meaning that a mountain can have multiple peaks ( In mathematics, it's called **local maximum**).

***Summit*** refers to the highest point in a mountain. Oxford:

> the highest point of a hill or mountain

and the word comes from the Latin root "summus", which means the highest. Every mountain has exactly one summit.

Having said that, <strike>most</strike> some mountaineers use these two words interchangeably.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'every mountain has exactly one summit'. I'm sure I've heard of a mountain's north summit and south summit, for example.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Exactly. For example you have "Everest South Summit". That's why I'm saying that in practice, the distinction between these two words is really blurred and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: I suppose that begins to beg the technical definition of mountain! Here we go again...

Answer (score 6):

The OED defines *summit*, in its topological sense, as ‘the topmost point or ridge of a mountain or hill’. For a *peak* it gives ‘the pointed top or summit of a mountain; a mountain or hill having a more or less pointed summit, or being conical in form.’ There is a clear difference here: peaks can be summits, but not all summits are peaks.

It would take a full search using a concordancer to establish the finer points of the distinction, but there are certainly some contexts in which they are not interchangeable. We might say ‘We’ll probably never know if Malory reached the summit of Everest’, but I don’t think we’d say ‘We’ll probably never know if Malory reached the peak of Everest’. The differences in figurative use are even greater.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia's “[topographical summit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographical_summit)” article says:

> In topography, a summit is a point on a surface that is higher in elevation than all points immediately adjacent to it. Mathematically, a summit is a local maximum in elevation. The topographic terms "acme", "apex", "peak", and "zenith" are synonyms.

Apparently  “synonyms” in that last sentence means “synonyms of summit”.  However, the article goes on to use the concept of *[topographic prominence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence)* (“also known as autonomous height, relative height, shoulder drop ... or prime factor”) to differentiate *summit* from its synonyms:

> The term "summit" is generally only used for a mountain peak with some significant amount of topographic prominence (height above the lowest point en route to the nearest higher peak) or topographic isolation (distance from the nearest point of higher elevation)

and then gives a few examples and  lists [UIAA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIAA) (a climbing association) criteria used to designate independent summits.

Regarding multiple summits on one mountain, the topographic prominence article uses Everest's South Summit (ca. 8749 m altitude) and main summit (ca. 8850 m altitude) as an example in explaining why K2 (ca. 8611 m altitude) rather than South Summit is the world's second highest mountain:

> While Mount Everest's South Summit ... is taller [than K2], it is a subsummit of the main summit. Only summits with a sufficient degree of prominence are regarded as independent mountains.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time they're used interchangably.
Peak requires the pointy shape though, which is part of it. Summit is the very top and is not defined by a pointed shape. It just means the very top.

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with all said before, the terms also have verb usages that are not so interchangable, even though they have very similar sense derivations.

According to the [American Heritage Dctionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/peak), the term *peak* is used as an intransitive verb to mean

> to achieve a maximum of development, value, or intensity: *Sales tend to peak just before the holidays.*

Similar definitions in [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/peak_19), and [Compact OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peak?view=uk).

The verb, *summit* means

> To climb to the summit of (a mountain)

according to [American Heritage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/summit), and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summit)

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of a mountain-climber and peakbagger, I'll try and explain the nuances between "peak" and "summit." Below are the three senses of the word "peak," each compared with "summit," but note they are very much on a continuous spectrum.

1. The very top/apex of a mountain or other independent eminence, usually a pointed one. This sense is synonymous with the most common definition of a summit but is used the least. "I fell just short of the peak."
2. A noteworthy or pointy eminence, usually in mountainous terrain, such as a rocky mound, spire or steep knoll. This might form the top of an entire mountain or be a subsidiary top with low prominence. A peak might be defined by a certain prominence cutoff, like 30m, but ordinarily an eminence is named a peak if it is rugged or otherwise visually conspicuous. This sense is the most common, and in its broadest usage, can apply to any eminence with notable prominence or simply the upper reaches of a mountain. "Summit" may also be used in this way, but less often. "I clambered up the small eastern peak."
3. An entire independent mountain, e.g. Granite Peak or Longs Peak. Mountains named in this way instead of "mount" or "mountain" tend to be more rugged/pointy/steep, but this isn't always the case. This sense is very much like sense 2, but isn't as specific to a subsidiary feature. "Summit" is rarely used in this sense, if at all. "It took all day to climb the peak."

The words "summit," "peak," and "top," tend to get used all over the place and it is very difficult to restrict any to one particular sense. In my opinion, "peak" is best used in sense 2, "summit" is best used in sense 1 followed by 2, and "top" is best suited to 1 and 2 but is fine when used in sense 3. "Mountain," obviously, is synonymous with only sense 3.

Comment: You could add some dictionary definitions to make this answer better - we try not to go by people's opinions, but by established facts, such as actual usage in reputable books etc.