# What is a wheal?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Indulging some idle curiosity about Cornish mining I noticed that many of the mines are named *wheal*: *[Wheal Kitty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheal_Kitty)*, *[Wheal Jane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheal_Jane)* and *[East Wheal Rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Wheal_Rose)*, among others.

But the only dictionary definition I can dig up explains *[wheal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wheal)* as:-

> 1. a small, burning or itching swelling on the skin, as from a mosquito bite or from hives.
> 2. a wale or welt.

This doesn't appear to be what is meant. There is also a mention in passing [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110492/how-to-refer-to-the-elevated-areas-of-a-mountain/110522#110522), but no clue as to the actual meaning. So, what is a *wheal*, in the mining sense of the word?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wheal   "Etymology 2"

Comment: Wheal \Wheal\, n. [Cornish hwel.] (Mining) A mine. [1913 Webster] http://wheal.askdefine.com/

Comment: "By Tre, Pol and Pen you will know the Cornishmen" http://www.intocornwall.com/features/cornish_language.asp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OED has

> **wheal** *n.3*
>   Etymology:  < Cornish *huel.*
>   *local.*
>
> A mine.
>
> > 1830   *Eng. & For. Mining Gloss.*

*Wheal* is an Anglicisation of the Cornish word.

It's interesting that Wiktionary's earliest citation appears to predate OED:

> 1829, Thomas Moore, *The History of Devonshire,* page 528,
>   The four last-mentioned mines, Wheal Crowndale, Wheal Crebor, East Liscombe, and Wheal Tamar, are on the same lode, which ranges as usual from east to west, and are included in a space of about four miles in length.

although since it contains data for 1830, it cannot have been published in 1829. [The book](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=efMGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA527&dq=%22wheal%22%7C%22wheals%22+mine&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6d5bUaL9IMGfkAWCu4G4CA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wheal&f=false) contains a better citation in the footnote on page 527:

> *Wheal* (or rather *huel*) is said to be derived from the Cornish language, and to signify a work or mine.

Answer (score 6):

It's just the local name for a mine, as *tor* is for a hill. The OED says it derives from Cornish *huel*, but I can find no such word in modern Cornish (though admittedly all variants of Cornish now in use were created some time after the mines closed down).

Comment: The modern variant is apparently _hwel_. According to [Jago’s 1887 dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/EnglishCornishDictionary/cornish_dictionary#page/n129/mode/2up/), the original meaning of the word (which he writes, _whêl, wheal, wheyl, wheil, whyl, wail, whela, wheela, huel, huêl, hwêl, hweyl_, and probably half a dozen other ways, too) is neither ‘mine’ nor ‘hole’, but **work**: a mine is ‘the workings’. A workman/worker is given as _dên huél_ (_dên_ = person, man), too. My knowledge of Cornish is far too limited to know if he’s right, though.

Answer (score 3):

In the beginning of the 11th out of 12 Poldark novels (set in Cornwall in the late 18th to the early 19th century); after bantering the word about through 11 thick novels, author Winston Graham finally revealed the full meaning of the word wheal, "It is from the Cornish, huel, meaning a hole."